# What happens when a visualforce page run on system mode?

Tags: visualforce

I came across this statement...

"*Use custom controllers when you want your Visualforce page to run entirely in system mode*"

in [custom controller definition](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_def.htm). What does running in system mode means? Can anyone explain in detail?

Thanks

Comment: But that was not well explained. Expecting a detailed one. Thanks.

Comment: Why wasn't that well explained? What part don't you understand or what do you want to know that's not in that post? I think Daniel Hoechst's answer should be satisfactory.

Comment: @Lex Thanks.  Daniel Hoechst's answer is indeed satisfactory.